# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException using RabbitMQ on EC2 Instance Ubuntu rabbitmq

Tags: java, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I am running an EC2 Instance RabbitMQ Ubuntu. I have started running the Rabbit MQ on it and it is listening on the public IPv4. I have provided a custom port number 15672, so it is hearing at `http://***AWS PUBLIC IP****:15672`. Everything is going but, when I am writing java code for both sender and receiver having error at host, which the aws public address and the rabbit mq port as well

Sender error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: http://52.90.84.218:15672
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:56)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
    at com.demo.Send.main(Send.java:19)
```

Reciever error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: http://52.90.84.218:15672
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:56)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
    at com.demo.Recv.main(Recv.java:24)
```

WHEN I AM using `localhost` as `factory.sethost("localhost");`

error as:

```
[AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured
com.rabbitmq.client.MalformedFrameException: AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 3,1,0,0
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.protocolVersionMismatch(Frame.java:170)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:107)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[AMQP Connection 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5672] ERROR com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured
com.rabbitmq.client.MalformedFrameException: AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 3,1,0,0
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.protocolVersionMismatch(Frame.java:170)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:107)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:353)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
    at com.demo.Recv.main(Recv.java:24)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.MalformedFrameException: AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 3,1,0,0
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.protocolVersionMismatch(Frame.java:170)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:107)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Let me know where If at all I am going wrong

java code for both sender and receiver:

```
package com.demo;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DefaultConsumer;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Envelope;

public class Recv {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                    byte[] body) throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
            }
        };
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);

    }

}
```

Sender code:

```
package com.demo;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("http://52.90.84.218:15672");
        Connection con = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = con.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello Santosh";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        channel.close();
        con.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: `UnknownHostException: http://52.90.84.218:15672` implies that you passed a URL to a method that expects a bare hostname or IP address.  I.e. the API was expecting just `52.90.84.218` and not a full URL

Answer (score 0):

```
UnknownHostException: http://52.90.84.218:15672
```

implies that you passed a URL to a method that expects a bare hostname or IP address. I.e. the API was expecting just `52.90.84.218` and not a full URL.

Thus where you have

```
factory.setHost("http://52.90.84.218:15672");
```

change it to

```
factory.setHost("52.90.84.218");
factory.setPort(15672);
```